# Automatically Convert Prices on a Web Page to A Different Currency

Tags: scripting, web, greasemonkey

I am interested in possible methods of automatically converting the prices given when a web page is loaded from the currency given to a specified currency.  Ideally, the conversion would also make use of the current exchange rate to give valid prices.

For example, in my specific case, I would like to convert the prices given in Euros (€) on this [web site](http://www.pumps.ie/index.php) to Sterling (£).

I am looking at using a GreaseMonkey script for this conversion, but can anyone suggest other methods?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the API: http://thecurrencygraph.com

It uses Geo Location scripts to detect the user's country and through that their native currency. It then converts your prices into their currency using the latest exchange rates

Hope this this helps!

W.

Answer (score 1):

Since I dabble in [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com) here's a potential solution using that scripting language, it retrieves the page source from a webpage that does the conversion and parses out the converted value.  This requires the [**httpQuery library**](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic33506.html) to be included:

```
#Include httpQuery.ahk

InputBox, n, EUR to GBP, Enter the number., , 150, 120
if (ErrorLevel || !n)
    return
url :=  "http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=" n "&From=EUR&To=GBP&image.x=55&image.y=8"
html := URLDownloadToVar(url)
Gui, Add, Edit, w125, % RegExMatch(html,"[\d\.]+(?= GBP)",m) ? m "£" : "The value could not be retrieved."
Gui, Show, AutoSize Center, GBP
VarSetCapacity(html,0)
Return

GuiClose: 
GuiEscape: 
Gui, Destroy
return

URLDownloadToVar(url){ 
    if !RegExMatch(url,"^http://") 
        url :=  "http://" url 
    httpQuery(html,url) 
    VarSetCapacity(html, -1) 
    Return html 
}
```

There are obviously more thorough (and complex) methods for solving this problem but this at least solves it with minimal effort.

Comment: southstexit, interesting, looking forward to trying it out.  +1  Also, I'm a big believer in the KISS principle - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy answer is to make use of a Firefox add-on.  There are a number of currency converters available as add-ons, but I ended up using [Exch](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1747), as it suited my needs best.